# iCal4J with calendarServer would fit this application?

Tags: java, calendar, icalendar, ical4j

i would like to offer our users a iCal they can include in their favorite calendar application.

Hosting the iCal files on the calendarServer (Darwin Calendar Server) and connect the server with the iCal4j framework could be a fit. Do you think this could work?
What would I like to offer:

1. users can view all the current appointement they did using my service
2. users canNOT add new events to the calendar
3. users can change the time of an event and the java webservice (spring in tomcat) can recognize this and react to this change
4. optional: users can receive a meeting request via mail. When they accept, the webservice shall be informed. Afterwards the new meeting shall appear in the calendar.

Which frameworks would you use to approach this problem? Would you use a ical server like calendarServer to host the ical file and change it over the api or would you host the ical file directly in the webserver?

Thanks a lot for sharing your experience!

Steve

Comment: did you ever get this app working?  I'm wanting to use calendarServer in my application.  Since I have my calendarServer on my umbunto server on AWS I was thinking that users of my application could log into the umbunto server for authentication.  I'm still a little foggy of how it all works.  It sure would be great if you could share your experience.  Thanks Andrew

Comment: I'm afraid I need to disappoint you. I didn't continue with this feature...